# Drag and Drop in VMWare

Tags: lxde, drag-and-drop

I installed LXDE desktop on Ubuntu 14.04 in VMWare. I try to drag files from Windows to Ubuntu but it does not work.

Comment: If I recall correctly, drag and drop probably needs VMware tools to be installed in the guest. Did you install them?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of  pcmanfm/libfm. There is a patch:

https://github.com/YustasSwamp/libfm/commit/a9ec8994dfcd267665f70a68230f1b8bad93048b

But copy/paste file should work in your case.